# Advanced Transfer Project Standards Functionality Using Revit API

Tags: plugins, revit, revit-api

I would like to create Revit plugin using Revit API for transferring project standards between multiple Revit projects. Is this possible using Revit API?

Comment: Yes, it's possible but it would be much more helpful if you had given us some more detail about some of the functionality that you wish to implement and or some of the "standards" you wish to transfer.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help at all?

http://autodesk-revit.blogspot.com/2008/11/managing-project-standards.html